# Remove ListView footer Click Listener

Tags: java, android, android-listview, footer, onitemclicklistener

ListView Footer

```
RelativeLayout listFooterView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.my_footer_layout, null);
getListView().addFooterView(listFooterView);
```

ListView OnClickListener

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Abc.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

On Click Listener works even if I click on footer View. How to disable click event on for footer.

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try to add your footer with this function: [addFooterView (View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29)

Try something like this:

```
RelativeLayout listFooterView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.my_footer_layout, null);
getListView().addFooterView(listFooterView,null,false);
```

Comment: How do toggle that behaviour once I've added the footer view? The only way I've found so far is to remove and add again the footer view (changing the true/false parameter), but I don't like that solution..